# Git-SVN and Zend Studio

Tags: git, ide, zend-studio

so I have started using git-svn at work because I hate the way branching is done in svn and I know how to use git effectively. My question is, since I am doing everything, git related, via command line - this includes branching, checking in and out and so on - I have one basic question:
when I make a branch in git, via git checkout -b "newbranch" and make changes in my IDE, then switch back to master - my project in the IDE does not update reflecting the fact that on one branch there are changes where as on another there are not.
Do I have to make a new a project for each branch made in git? - I would think not as the project points to the folder which contains the .git folder and the checkout.
so why is the project in the IDE not updating to relfect the different branches?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to do the branching directly in Zend Studio, it will manage those changes very well. You can enable the Git connector at the welcome screen. Restart ZS and it will detect a Git project by itself. Do not try however to use git-svn as, as far as I know, it isn't implemented yet.

2) If you don't want to, you must refresh the project (select project, F5 or right click and select refresh). ZS will do this eventually, but sometimes it is slower than doing so yourself.

3) Check whether auto-refresh is enabled (Team - Git - Refresh resources when index changes), however I don't think a new branch is an index change.

Greetings.